# What is the Standalone Kind Signature for this class?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, data-kinds, singleton-type

I am trying to move the kind annotation for `i` from the class below to a SAKS:

```
class Demote t (i :: t -> Type) where
    demote :: forall (t' :: t) . i t' -> t
```

The following attempts did not work:

```
-- fails because k and t will not unify?
type Demote :: Type -> (k -> Type) -> Constraint
class Demote t i where
    demote :: forall (t' :: t) . i t' -> t

-- fails because the SAKS and class head do not share the same namespace?
type Demote :: (k ~ t) => Type -> (k -> Type) -> Constraint
class Demote t i where
    demote :: forall (t' :: t) . i t' -> t
```

Is there no way to write a SAKS for this in GHC 9.2.0.20210422?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of *visible dependent quantification* (`forall->`), the kind is

```
--
--    Demote :: forall (t :: Type) -> ..
--
type  Demote :: forall t -> (t -> Type) -> Constraint
class Demote t i where
  demote :: forall (t' :: t) . i t' -> t
```

It is dependent because the result depends on the type we pass in:

```
>> :k Demote
.. :: forall t -> (t -> Type) -> Constraint
>> :k Demote Bool
.. :: (Bool -> Type) -> Constraint
>> :k Demote [Nat]
.. :: ([Nat] -> Type) -> Constraint
```

Any kind that is polymorphic `forall.` can be made visible `forall->`.

```
type Proxy :: forall k. k -> Type
data Proxy a where
  Proxy :: Proxy @k a

type ProxyVDQ :: forall k -> k -> Type
data ProxyVDQ k a where
  ProxyVDQ :: ProxyVDQ k a
```